# Header cookies not being set by another subdomain?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have two subdomais "api.domain.com" and "web.domain.com".
Now "web.domain.com" is web page written in html/javascript and "api.domain.com" is a simple restful API server written in php.

"api.domain.com" sets certain cookies in the header as follows

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
setcookie("TestCookie", "Some Value", time()+3600, "/", ".domain.com", 0);
```

Now, when I make an ajax call (using jQuery.ajax() ) from "web.domain.com" to "api.domain.com", the **response** headers contain

```
Set-Cookie:abc=802691344656c1d0899c4a74.87956617; expires=Mon, 16-May-2016 21:00:09 GMT; path=/; domain=domain.com,
```

so i guess a cookie should be set in the client browser at "web.domain.com".

The next time I make another request to "api.domain.com" from "web.domain.com", shouldn't this cookie go as part of the **request** headers?

However, when I inspect the $_COOKIE array at "api.domain.com", i don't see this cookie! Does that mean the cookie never got set in the client ("web.domain.com") at the first place? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To start, you should check in the browser tools what cookies are set where exactly.

Comment: cookies aren't sent cross domain unless you use withCredentials header

Comment: Also, `.domain.com` is not a valid domain name.

Comment: @charlietfl : Where should I set the withCredentials header? In request or response? In the response I'm already setting : header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

Comment: @Cristy , the "." was a typo. I'm setting "domain.com"

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl . I'll try out your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Using the withCredentials header (as suggested by @charlietfl) worked for me. I had to make one more modification in the server as well.
So here's what I did. 
In web.domain.com , while maqking the Ajax request, I added **withCredentials: true** , like this

```
   $.ajax({
            // The Url for the request
            url : ajaxUrl,

            // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
            data : ajaxData,

            xhrFields: {
              // To allow cross domain cookies
              withCredentials: true
           },
...
});
```

In api.domain.com , I set some headers like this :

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

However, I was still unable to get any response. I got this error instead

```
Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.
```

So i simply set the header to the origin domain, like so :

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if (substr($input, -10) == 'domain.com') { // To check if request is always from a subdomain of 'domain.com'
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

That fixed the issue.